# find the limit by using Riemann sum

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, definite-integrals

My question is

Find the limit \begin{equation}
\lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{(3k-2n)^{5}}{n^{6}}?
\end{equation}

I just need a hint. I try to see this limit as a Riemann sum. For this I consider $$ P=\{0<\ldots <\frac{1}{3^{6}}<\frac{1}{2^{6}}<1\}$$ as a partition of [0,1]. Thus $||P||=\frac{1}{n^{6}} \rightarrow +\infty.$ However I don't know how to follow this idea.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is $\int_0^{1} (3x-2)^{5}dx$. To see this write it as $\lim_n \frac1 n \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} (3\frac k n-2)^{5}$ and divide $[0,1]$ into $n$ equal parts.

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

$lim_{n\to +\infty} \sum _{k=1}^{n}  \frac{(3k-2n)^5 }{n^6} = lim_{n\to +\infty}  \frac{1}{n}\sum _{k=1}^{n}  (\frac{3k-2n}{n})^5 = lim_{n\to +\infty}  \frac{1}{n}\sum _{k=1}^{n}  (\frac{3k}{n}-2)^5$

We put $f(x) = (3x-2)^5$

$lim_{n\to +\infty}  \frac{1-0}{n}\sum _{k=1}^{n}  (f(0+\frac{(1-0)k}{n})$ =$\int_{0}^{1} (3x-2)^5 dx$

Because f is continous at $[0,1]$

$\int_{0}^{1} (3x-2)^5 dx$ =$\frac{1}{3}\int_{0}^{1}3 (3x-2)^5 dx $ =$\frac{1}{3}[\frac{1}{6}(3x-5)^6]^1_0$.